# How to do static methods?

Tags: java, methods, static, static-methods

I have this code and I am missing static fields. How do I do static fields in this program? Do I also need instance fields?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Geometry
{

    public static double sphereVolume(double r)
    {
        double svol=(4.0/3.0)*Math.PI*(Math.pow(r,3));
        return svol;
    }

    public static double sphereSurface(double r)
    {
        double ssur=4.0*Math.PI*(Math.pow(r,2));
        return ssur;
    }

    public static double cylinderVolume(double r, double h)
    {
        return (Math.PI*r*r*h);
    }

    public static double cylinderSurface(double r, double h)
    {
        double csur=2*(Math.PI*(Math.pow(r,2)))+(2*Math.PI*r)*h;
        return csur;
    }

    public static double coneVolume(double r, double h)
    {
        return (Math.PI/3.0)*h*(Math.pow(r,2));
    }

    public static double coneSurface(double r, double h)
    {
        return Math.PI*r*r+Math.PI*r*Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r,2)+(Math.pow(h,2)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the radius?");
        String input=in.nextLine();
        double r=Double.parseDouble(input);
        System.out.println("The volume of the sphere:"+sphereVolume(r));
        System.out.println("The Surface Area of the sphere:"+sphereSurface(r));

        System.out.println("The Surface Area of the sphere:"+cylinderSurface(r,h));
        System.out.println("The volume of the cone:"+coneVolume(r,h));
        System.out.println("The Surface Area of the cone:"+coneSurface(r,h));
    }
}
```

Comment: Static variables can be defined as static double variablename;

Answer (score 0):

Because you are in a Static Context, without any reference of your Geometry class you need to specify where those methods are called from like this:

```
 System.out.println("The volume of the sphere:"+Geometry.sphereVolume(r));
```

Comment: it shouldn't matter as the main method is already in the same class

Answer (score 0):

You should first understand what are instance and static members and then you can have a better understanding and can easily relate to the syntax.

Instance members/variables: Memory is allocated to them on per object basis. Whenever a new object is created, the object will have all the instance variables as a part of it.

Static members/variables: They are created per class basis not on per object basis. Hence in order to access them you just need the name of the class (ClassName.member). No need to specify any object reference while referring them, since they are associated with the Class rather than the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes for static field you need static keyword to associate the fields to the type you declared.

```
private static double variable;
```

No you don't need to create an object instance, creating object instance is like putting everything inside that object box of instance, i.e. those fields now belong to instance however with static the fields belongs to types they are associated or declared in that is why **Geometry.SomeVariable** will have same field irrelevant to instances.